# Chrome cannot parse single line JSONP object

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I'm having issues getting this JSON object to load via JSONP in Chrome 18 (latest stable). For some reason it presents me the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`. According to JSONLint, the response is a valid JSON object.

Here is the code example: http://jsfiddle.net/jakebellacera/2j7DL/1/

To add: I'm attempting to get around cross-domain, I have permissions to both servers, but we cannot allow cross-domain on a specific domain for specific reasons. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Don't all the internal `{,},[,]` entities have to be escaped? I thought the JSON parser handles turning it into valid JSON...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server at lpunderground.com is returning JSON, not JSONP.

What's special about JSONP is that it's a valid javascript statement - the data returned from the server is wrapped in a function call (or sometimes a variable assignment) and when returned it is evaluated as normal javascript.  Typically the client passes the server in the request parameters a function name to use in wrapping the data.

See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the details.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was just a little confused as to if jQuery had a way of "wrapping" a JSON object in a callback function... but that didn't make sense to me as that'd be accessing cross-domain stuff anyways. I guess I just needed some validation, either way -- thanks!